# shopify-api-java-wrapper : what is a node address?

Tags: java, shopify, nodes

I am trying to implement the shopify-api-java-wrapper found on on github. I would like to use this to connect to my shop. I have written the below code:

```
    String accessToken = "[many digits and letters here]";
    String myShopifyUrl = "https://[my shop name].myshopify.com";
    String nodeAddress = "[???]";

    ShopifyApiClient client = ShopifyApiFactory.create(accessToken, myShopifyUrl, nodeAddress );
    client.getProductsCount();
```

The accessToken was the one I was given when activating Storefront API for my app on the Shopify dashboard.

But I don't know what a nodeAddress is. What should I write here? Could you please assist me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your redis/redisson service host.

(java wrapper for redis)
https://www.baeldung.com/redis-redisson